# Parse Json Xcode

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, parsing

I'm am pretty new at Xcode iOS and can't figure out how to parse this json:

```
  {
  "status": 0,
  "result": {
    "user_guid": 1158,
    "token": "kl7859ee0a9kd27b65k344791d3d754e",
    "new_user": "true"
  }
}
```

I am trying to parse "token" out but can't figure out how.  How would I go about parsing this?

Comment: you need to fetch result and then fetch token , but before this you need to parse this using nsjsonserialization metthod

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Objective-C:**

```
NSString *jsonText = @"Your json string";
NSData *jsonData = [jsonText dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


NSDictionary *dic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData
                                                            options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                              error:nil];
NSString *token = [[dic valueForKey:@"result"] valueForKey:@"token"];
```

**Swift 3.0:**

```
let jsonText = "Your json string"

if let jsonData = jsonText.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) {
    do {
        let dic = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: .mutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
        let token:String = (dic.value(forKey: "result") as! NSDictionary).value(forKey: "token") as! String
        NSLog("%@", token)
    } catch {
        debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Comment: I receive this error when running it "Use of unresolved identifier 'NSJSONReadingMutableContainers'

Comment: No problem! Happy swifting!!

Comment: Badhan Ganesh - I have another question regarding json.  How to loop through a json array.  I have the json array I would like to parse through and gather user info in it.  Is this something you could help me with?  If not its ok, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Fetch the data from the end point. Then it's something like this:

```
if let dict = <insert response object> as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
if let token = dict["token"] as? String {
// Set the string to the value in app. 
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

let value = response.value(forKeyPath: "result.token") as! NSString